# Why is a private member visible when initializing a static variable?

Tags: c++, class, static, language-lawyer, private

This compiles:

```
class Node{
    int m = 0;

    static unsigned f(){
        return 1;
    }

public:
    static unsigned a;
    static unsigned b;
};

unsigned Node::a = sizeof(m); // <= !!!
unsigned Node::b = f();       // <= !!!

int main(){
}
```

Why? I know `sizeof` is not function but still, aren't `m` and `f()` private?

It is definitely not a bug, because the code compiles on GCC, MSVC, Clang and Intel C++.

Update: Also, note that it is just `sizeof(m)` and not `sizeof(Node::m)`; same with `f()` instead of `Node::f()`. (Koenig's lookup?)

Comment: What book on C++ did you read? Consider looking into [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) and taking inspiration from existing C++ open source code

Comment: yes. member is private

Comment: I'll update the question

Comment: While [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Definition_outside_of_its_namespace) is for namespace symbols, it seems to be the same here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is what I think so, but I can not be 100% sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Access to `private` members is allowed in non-inline definitions of static data members, because the ***initializer*** part of the definition (that is, the RHS of the `=`) is **in the scope** of the class, [according to the Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.static#data-3) ("Note 1", below):

> ##### 11.4.9.3 Static Data Members       [class.static.data]
>
> …
> <sup>3</sup>   The declaration of a non-inline static data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv void.
> *[Note 1: The initializer in the definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class ([basic.scope.class]). — end note]*
> …

---

Note that, in reference to your last (update) paragraph, because the initializer is in the class scope, unqualified/un-scoped variables, such as `m` and `f()` in your case, will by default refer to class members (if such exist); so, the `f()` call in your code is entirely equivalent to `Node::f()`.

Comment: As for the last sub-question, I can find a quote for that in an earlier (C++17) Draft Standard but not (so far) in the latest, online Draft I linked in my answer. It's 12.2.3, #3 in [this Draft C++17 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) ...

Comment: ... 3 If an unqualified-id (8.4) is used in the definition of a static member following the member’s declarator-id,
and name lookup (6.4.1) finds that the unqualified-id refers to a static member, enumerator, or nested type
of the member’s class (or of a base class of the member’s class), the unqualified-id is transformed into a
qualified-id expression in which the nested-name-specifier names the class scope from which the member is
referenced. [ Note: See 8.4 for restrictions on the use of non-static data members and non-static member
functions. — end note ]

Answer (score 1):

See [[class.access.general]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access.general#6), emphasis mine:

> All access controls in [class.access] affect the ability to name a class member from the declaration of a particular entity, including parts of the declaration preceding the name of the entity being declared and, **if the entity is a class, the definitions of members of the class appearing outside the class's *member-specification***. [Note 5: This access also applies to implicit references to constructors, conversion functions, and destructors.
> — end note]

The definition of `Node::a`, being a member of `Node`, has access to all names to which `Node` has access.